# Transformational generative grammar

Tags: theoretical-linguistics

Based on the theory of transformational generative grammar .what is the difference between complements and modifiers

Comment: There is no single thing "transformational generative grammar". Usually the term is applied to the Aspects model, where there were actual rules. "Complement" and "modifier" are not concepts of that theory: I assume that you mean "what is the Aspects analysis of what would *now* be called 'complements' and 'modifiers' in theory X (name that theory, please)?".

Comment: As noted, there is no single generative theory of grammar. The _Aspects_ model never worked, and various extensions, revisions, additions, interpretations, and technical terms (to say nothing of non-terminal nodes, which proliferated like angels on pinheads) have been proposed. Since no one accepts all of them, it's hard to pin down any terminology precisely. The distinction between a "complement" and  a "modifier" is one such. These terms (which are not distinctive in all theories) get used in a LOT of ways. I don't think anything real depends on the distinction, though.

Comment: It's about 'licensing'. Matthews in The Concise Oxford Dictionary of Linguistics defines a complement as 'A syntactic element seen as completing the construction of another element' (BillJ: the syntactic concept construction is preferable to the semantic concept meaning). He goes on to say, more specifically, that it applies to elements other than the subject which are within the valency of a verb or other lexical unit. And his entry for 'valency' is: 'The range of syntactic elements either required or specifically permitted by a verb or other lexical unit’ – which is equivalent to licensing.